# How to turn off Eclipse warning "The import is never used"?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, warnings

I have a lot of this warnings in project and I would like to turn it off. I'm not interested in removing those imports, so **please** don't tell me how to do it.

I'm using eclipse 3.4.2.

Comment: side comment: why don't you use the latest Eclipse? Is there any particular reason?

Comment: @nanda not everyone has the luxury of using the latest of everything, other constraints kick in, e.g. (potential) issues with a dependant plugin that is not available in the latest version or maybe the op is at a critical point in the project without time to sort out all those glitches that appear

Comment: I know the most common reasons, but 3.4 is more than 2 years old so and I'm not sure I know any plugins that is not working with more recent version of Eclipse. Please enlighten me!

Comment: @nanda off top of my head its clearcase plugin. But I do know there are many others.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To change for the entire workspace:

Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Unused Import > Ignore.

To override workspace settings for a single project:

Project > Properties > Java Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Unused Import > Ignore.

Comment: And in Python it's *Pydev > Editor > Code Analysis*. This is a generic Eclipse issue across languages, not just Java.

Answer (score 8):

@SuppressWarnings("unusedImports") disables just unused imports as opposed to al unused items

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("unusedImports")` is certainly better in this case than `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`, but would need to be applied to each class individually. Changing the Workspace settings, as I suggested in my answer, is a single change. If you only want the change to impact one project, instead of the whole workspace, you could override in Project > Properties > Java Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Unused Import > Ignore.

Comment: I agree and upvoted your answer.  I added that in reply to a previous comment about "unused", added this as an answer as the comment reply wasn't working, guess that was because it was deleted!  Adding @SuppressWarnings is probably unacceptable for the same reason removing the imports is, which means editing the code (as you mentioned)

Answer (score 3):

Btw, one very good shortcut is ctrl+shift+o that cleans those imports automatically.

Also it is possible to put so that in every save imports are automatically organised from:

```
window->preference->java->editor->save actions
```

If you prefer to leave those imports there, it is ok. But that is to anyone else :)

Also I am not sure about 3.4 version.

Comment: as I said its not what I want. I just don't like to be in SVN history as a person that has touched every file for no reason, but thats just me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` then you can add `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedImport=ignore`.

When using vscode this file should be seen from the project root in a folder `.settings`.